# function to erase swear words

Tags: functions

Does anyone use a function that will just not print swear words? We don't have any, and we edit for them, but in giving more writers more publishing privileges, it could lead to a situation with swear words. I'd rather just not print the words, possibly.

Comment: Would this work? https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-content-filter/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Basic Filtering**

This is just a simple example and would work if you're just using it for editors that might slip up here or there and put in a swear word by accident. However, if you have to worry about people trying to "spoof" their words for example *"focker, fuker, etc"* then you'll probably need something more complex.

```
// Basic Implementation
function replace_words($content) {
    // $content = preg_replace("/hate/", "love", $content);
    $content = str_replace('hate', 'love', $content);
    $content = str_replace('foo', 'bar', $content);
    $content = str_replace('bad', 'good', $content);
return $content;
}

// Filter options
add_filter('the_content','replace_words', 2);
add_filter('the_excerpt','replace_words', 2);
add_filter('widget_text','replace_words', 2);
//add_filter('get_comment_text','replace_words', 11);
//add_filter('get_comment_excerpt','replace_words', 11);
```

*Or if you have a bunch of words, you can do this in an array*:

```
function replace_words($text){
        $replace = array(
                // 'BAD WORD' => 'GOOD WORD'
                'crap' => 'poop',
                'boob' => 'breast',
                'ugly' => 'pretty'
        );
        $text = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text);
        return $text;
}
```

Also, just watch out if using the example above because you might run into a situation where you filter out something you didn't mean to... Think "hell" which could have actually been the word "hello".

**PHPMYADMIN MYSQL**

This allows you to replace words in mysql but isn't a great solution if this is something you need constantly...

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (
post_content,
'hate',
'love');
```

**Plugins**

There's tons of plugins to do this, just try some of them out...

[WP Content Filter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-content-filter/)

[Word Filter Plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/word-filter-plus/)

[Web Purify](https://wordpress.org/plugins/webpurifytextreplace/)

[Text Obfuscator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/text-obfuscator/)

[Profanity Blocker](https://wordpress.org/plugins/profanityblocker-profanity-filter/)

[Replace Default Words](https://wordpress.org/plugins/replace-default-words/screenshots/)

[Bleep Filter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bleep-filter/)

Thats just to name a few too. Your best bet in these situations is to just do a search for something like "profanity", "replace text", or "content filter" in the wordpress plugins directory....

***Example Search:***

https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?type=term&q=replace+text

Comment: Might be good to add the on save case - https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post